# Save image to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage

from the following source file, I try to load image and save to Core Data and also show in the imageView but it doesnt work
Could you help me to fix it.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Telling the AddTrackingTVC Delegate that save was tapped on the     AddTrackingTVC");

    [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddPlantNoteTVCWasTapped:self];

    MyPlant *myTracking = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyPlant" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    myTracking.name = nameTextField.text;
    myTracking.detail = detailTextField.text;
    myTracking.createdDate = [NSDate date];
    //myTracking.photo = [NSData ];
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil]; // write data to database
    [self.delegate theSaveButtonOnTheAddPlantNoteTVCWasTapped:self];
}




- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    // If our device has a camera, we want to take a picture, otherwise, we // just pick from photo library
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]; }
    else {
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]; }
    // This line of code will generate a warning right now, ignore it
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    // Place image picker on the screen
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.currentEntry.photo = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info   objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage], 1.0);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

So what i have to do with these function to make it be able to save image to core data?

[Download source files](http://www.filedropper.com/plantnote)

Comment: Please be aware that most people are cautious (at best) about downloading .zip files. It would easier for us to understand the issue if you post some relevant code, and highlight parts that are giving you trouble.

Comment: Please identify the relevant part of the source code that's at issue and include it in your question.

Comment: I'd really recommend saving the image to disk and saving the *path* in core data--

Answer (score 5):

This is how I do it:

```
NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/picture.png"];
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSData *savedImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[coreDataObject setValue:savedImageData forKey:@"image"];
```

And when you want to show it:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[coreDataObject valueForKey:@"image"]];
```